# FInd the minimum value if the function $f(x)=\sqrt{4x^2-4x+2}+|x|$

Tags: calculus, functions

For the function $f(x)=\sqrt{4x^2-4x+2}+|x|$ the minimum value of $f(x)=$

My approach is as follow $f(x)=2\sqrt{(x-\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{1}{4}}+|x|$

For the term in square root we get minimum at $x=\frac{1}{2}$ but the absolute term value occurs at $x=0$. But not able to find the value for which value of $x$, $f(x)$ is minimum.

Comment: How about consider $x>=0$ and $x<0$ separately? Then you compare the function values at those critical points.

Comment: You've shown that the expression under the radical is never negative that's good.... maybe divide up the range of values in the domain.  Consider all positive x, take the  derivative and then all negative x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Split into two cases, depending on $|x|$.

**Case 1**: $x\geqslant 0$. In this case, $f(x)=\sqrt{4x^2-4x+2}+x$, so $$f'(x)=\frac{8x-4}{2\sqrt{4x^2-4x+2}}+1,$$
and solving $f'(x)=0$ gives $x=\frac16(3-\sqrt 3)$. For this value of $x$, $f(x)=\frac{1+\sqrt3}2$.

**Case 2**: $x<0$. In this case, $f(x)=\sqrt{4x^2-4x+2}-x$, and the derivative is the same as above but with $-1$. Solving $f'(x)=0$ gives $x=\frac{3+\sqrt3}6$, but this is not $<0$, and this is the only possible critical point. So there is no critical point, unless possibly when $x=0$ (the endpoint). At that value, $f(0)=\sqrt2$.

Since $\sqrt2>\frac{1+\sqrt3}2$, then the minimum occurs at $x=\frac16(3-\sqrt 3)$.

Comment: For the negative case easier approaches are available $f'(x)<0$ is immediate (as $8x-4<0$ as well as $-1$) so $f$ decreasing and min in $f(0)$, also OP formulation shows $(x-\frac 12)^2\ge \frac 14$ and $|x|\ge 0$ so whole expression $\ge \sqrt{2}$.